# Comparar id em duas tabelas e retornar valor da promocão sql

Tags: c#, sql

Olá!
Na minha tabela de produto e na tabela de promoção constam idcategoria, tenho meu produto com determinada categoria e quando encontrar o mesmo idcategoria na tabela de promoção e esta estiver com estado ativo, retornar o valor do desconto da promoção(tabela promoção). É possível fazer em uma consulta?

Comment: Pesquise por outer join https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Jun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_externa_(outer_join)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,
ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT DESCONTO, IDPRODUTO FROM PRODUTOS P
INNER JOIN PROMOCAO PR ON PR.IDCATEGORIA = P.IDCATEGORIA
WHERE P.IDPRODUTO = X AND PR.ATIVO = 1;
```

> PR.ATIVO = 1 NÃO SEI O QUE VC SALVA COMO TRUE OU FALSE MAS NORMALMENTE
> É 0 FALSE E 1 ATIVO.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou! Muito obrigada!